# C visit visa issue

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My C visit visa was approved. In my application I have highlighted that I will travel to the UK to perform assembly of automatic warehouse, which a UK company has bought from an Italian company.

On my visa it says "No work or ressource to public funds".

My question is, will I be able to do the assembly work with this visa?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You're fine.** The activity that you describe falls within the scope of [permitted activities](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).

> **Manufacturing and supply of goods to the UK**
>
> An employee of a foreign manufacturer or supplier may install, dismantle, repair, service or advise on equipment, computer software or hardware where it has a contract of purchase or supply or lease with a UK company or organisation.

Secondly, you applied for a visa and told them what you intend to do, if that was not allowed they would have sent a clear refusal letter. **Work** is not just about any work.